# Fit an ellipse with known semi-major-axis and points

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

In my particular case I am given a projection of a circle onto the $xy$-plane and the radius $r$ of said circle. This results in an ellipse with semi-major axis $a$ equal to $r$.

Like in [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773126/find-normal-vector-of-circle-in-3d-space-given-circle-size-and-a-single-perspect) I want to find the orientation of the circle -- meaning the normal vector and its origin. But contrary to the linked question, I cannot determine the bounds of the ellipse, as my image contains too much noise. Therefore I first need to fit an ellipse to the image. I plan to do this via the [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) method. So you can consider $n$ points on the ellipse as given (with $n$ being just as large as it needs to be).

As I don't know the orientation of my ellipse, the canonical form $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ doesn't help me, so I assume I'll need the analytical form:

$$px^2+qxy+ry^2+sx+ty+u=0$$

The semi-major axis $a$ does not appear in this formula and is also not directly involved in any of the constants -- at least not without also knowing the center point of the ellipse (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse) for details). How many points do I need to fix the ellipse? How do I calculate any set of parameters that defines the ellipse?

**What I have:**

- $a$: The length of the semi-major axis
- $P$: A set of at least $n$ points $p_i(x_i|y_i)$ on the ellipse
- A method to determine whether the calculated ellipse fits the image

**What I do not have:**

- The center point of the ellipse
- The orientation of the ellipse
- The semi-minor axis

**What I need:**

- $n$: The number of points necessary to fix the ellipse. I suspect it to be 3, because $a$ is given, but I am not sure.
- $S$: A set of parameters defining the ellipse, dependent on $a$ and $P$.

Assume a general non-degenerate ellipse for the answer.

Comment: As a general rule, you need $5$ points to define an ellipse. Indeed, the equation features $5$ independant parameters.

Comment: Your canonical form is an ellipse, non-shifted, non-rotated and having radius 0, thus it is the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: What set of parameters do you need? The $A, \ldots F$ of $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 + Dx + E y + F = 0$?

Comment: Or $a,b,\theta,C$ with $C$ being the center point and $\theta$ the orientation of the major axis. Any set that defines the ellipse would do.